# Variable passed as parameter returning undefined JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to pass a variable which stores a cookie name in JS, the correct value is stored when writing the cookie but when passed to the function to read the cookie it returns undefined, returning the cookie value as NULL. It is for a college project, and I am working from the code example on this site here https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

```
function WriteCookie(cname, username) {

  //Cookies variables
  var cname = 'user';
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;

  //check if the user has entered a value and alert if they haven't
  if (document.myform.username.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a value in the name field");
    document.getElementById("username").focus();
    return false
  }

  //variables for emial validation
  var emailtext = document.myform.email.value;
  var pos_of_at = emailtext.indexOf('@');

  //checking email address for an @
  if (pos_of_at <= 0) {
    alert("Invalid Email");
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  }

  //store the cookie 
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + username + "; path=/";
  location.href = 'welcome.html';
}

//function to read the cookie
function readCookie(cname) {
  //variable for loop
  var nameEQ = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)
  }
  return null;
}

function cookiealert() {
  alert(readCookie());
}
```

Comment: You're not passing the argument to `readCookie()`.

Comment: the code you're *"working from"* even states ... *To read out a cookie, call this function **and pass the name of the cookie***

Comment: `writeCookie` also isn't using the parameters that it's given. It overwrites `cname` with `'user'`, and gets the username from an input field instead of the function parameters.

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial on function parameters.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out to me. I'll spend some more time looking at function parameters before I continue on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're using `httponly` cookie causing this.

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies):

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Therefore, your for loop does not return any value and the function returns back `null`.